# Button without form looks bad in Firefox

Tags: html, css, django, forms, button

I have a button that's not associated with a form per se, but basically only serves as a hyperlink.  It looks fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox, there's an ugly extra line behind it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IndYp.png

(The faint grey line above it is intentional, the thicker line behind it is what I'm trying ot get rid of)

I have the following in my HTML template (it's Django, but that doesn't really matter):

```
<p class="submitrow"><form><a href="{% url events_create_event %}"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Create New Event" /></form></p>
```

Getting rid of the  tags doesn't change anything.

How can I make my button look normal in Firefox too?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use a button if you what a hyperlink?

Comment: It might be useful to show the CSS associated with (and around) the button.

Comment: Get the webdeveloper toolbar addon, and use its css-> view style infomation to work out what is causing the line to render: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ Maybe the form is styled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need `text-decoration: none` on the `a`.

Also, you can't have an `<input>` inside an `<a>`- [it's invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Famewex&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2).

Additionally, you're missing an `</a>`, and you can't have a `<form>` inside a `<p>`.

Basically, sort out your invalid HTML and problem will sort itself out.

Comment: I changed the <a> to a <form action="blah"> and it fixed the problem, thanks!